How to store a date without time in Core Data?
We download data from a server that returns dates without times (e.g., "2024-01-01"). We parse these dates into a UTC date (Date) and store in Core Data.
We're running into problems where users that are in timezones behind GMT (e.g., EST or PST) are seeing these dates being displayed in the wrong calendar day (e.g., January 1st 2024 is displayed as December, 31st 2023). Further, filtering and other logic is not working as expected.
To fix, we can update the DateFormatter instances to use GMT timezone, however, if I go down this route, does it mean that I need to convert from local to UTC times everywhere I filter and edit these dates? This feels a little clunky and prone to errors.
I have seen some alternatives this where people use their own format for dates (e.g., number of days since an offset value). But, I'm also wondering if an approach would be to preserve the original ISO8601 string and store this in the CoreData? I think that this would allow searching and sorting due to the format. We could then convert to a local Date using ISO8601DateFormatter for use with date pickers and formatters.
Would performance be a concern (string sorting and filtering vs numeric or the conversion from String > Date)?
I'm not sure whether I'm missing something and making life overly complicated... or whether we're dealing with dates, so it's going to be complicated!

Dates in Core Data, and in Swift, always include the time of day, because they're really just the number of seconds since a reference date and time. It's not the best name, because the word "date" doesn't obviously imply time. A date also does not include any time zone information-- it represents the same instant everywhere, not just in one zone.
Keeping the string as something like "2024-01-01" would work and would be searchable and sortable. However this would be much much slower than doing a numeric search (which is how dates work).
If you want Jan 1 2024 to always appear as Jan 1 2024 in your UI, regardless of the local time zone, there are a couple of options.
One is to make sure you store the dates as UTC (which you should do anyway) and then also represent them as UTC rather than local time in the UI. As long as the time zone is consistent, you're set. Use whatever date format you like for the UI and it'll work. This is the most correct way to do things, but of course real code doesn't always need to follow the ideal perfect way.
Another is to store both the string and the date in Core Data. Use the date only for searching and sorting, and use the string for the UI. This may be simpler. It's less clean in that you're saving two fields where you only need one, and it makes it harder to change the date format in the UI, but it'll work just fine.

I agree, using a UTC date feels correct. Displaying is relatively straightforward because, as you say, the timezone just needs to be set on the DateFormatter. However, it's editing, filtering and other business logic that I'm finding awkward as it looks like all of those inputs need to be converted from the local date into UTC (system date pickers normally work with Date).

Some use midday (instead of start of the day) UTC that way you'll almost alway have the same day whichever time zone you're in, but in fact there is +13 and +14 which make that solution working for almost everyone, but not everyone. And indeed, dates and timezone are a complex thing, which a lot of subtlety once you don't use only your "country/time zone".

thank you, I've seen some suggestions around using midday, but I feel that this is just kicking can down the road.

I did run some performance tests with date vs ISO date string and found that on a data set with around 40k records (each record three columns: ID, DateAsDate, DateAsString + core data's cols) and found that sort and filter performance was much about the same if the work was done in the DB. However, sort performance was significantly worse if sorting in code (3x worse) (Tested on iPhone 7Plus, iOS 15.8). Also, converting from String > Date adds a significant overhead. Not sure if there are other considerations when measuring performance?
